# Spectral theorem asked by a physicist

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

In physics we use the fact that, given a self adjoint operator A, every element in Hilbert space can be written as "generalized linear combination" of the eigenstates of A:

$$\tag{1} \psi(x)=\sum a_k \psi_k(x) +\int c(\lambda)\psi_\lambda(x) d\lambda $$

Where the integral is over the continuous spectrum.

If the dimension of H is finite, the spectral theorem guarantees that this expression is valid for all self adjoint operators with no continuous part.

In the case of infinite dimension spectral theorem says that every A self adjoint is unitary equivalent to a multiplication operator, that is, via basis change, we have

$$UTU^{-1}(\psi)(x)= f(x)\psi(x)$$

In which way is this related to the possibility to write every state in the form $(1)$?

Comment: I think you need not only "generalized linear combination" but "generalized eigenstates", because your $\psi_\lambda$ are unlikely to be actual elements of the Hilbert space.

Comment: (Specifically, the $\psi_k$'s in the discrete part belong to the Hilbert space, and those in the continuous part do not.)

Answer (score 4):

Okay. Every self-adjoint operator $A$ is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator on some measure space $X$. Let's assume $\|A\| \leq 1$. We can write $X = X_0 \cup X_1$ where $X_0$ is discrete and $X_1$ is atomless. The standard basis vectors in $L^2(X_0)$ are eigenvectors for any multiplication operator, so any element of $L^2(X_0)$ is an $l^2$ linear combination of these eigenvectors.

Now suppose $X_1$ is $[-1,1]$ equipped with some atomless measure $\mu$ and $A$ acts on $L^2(X_1)$ by multiplication by $x$. Then you may want to say that any $f \in L^2(X_1)$ has the form $f = \int_{[-1,1]} f(x)\delta_x\, d\mu$, where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac delta at $x$ is thought of as an eigenfunction of $A$. Whatever meaning you give to that expression is the answer to your question, because any self-adjoint multiplication operator on a separable Hilbert space is unitarily equivalent to the direct sum of a multiplication operator on a countable discrete space and multiplication by $x$ on countably many copies of $[-1,1]$, each equipped with an atomless measure. This is some version of the spectral theorem.

Comment: Aside: for spectral theorem in nonspeparable Hilbert space, see the Halmos book *Introduction to Hilbert Space and the Theory of Spectral Multiplicity*

Comment: What is specifically "X"? Have I to imagine it as a set of infinitesimal (or finite) subsets of R^3 who i can associate a "volume"? What "discrete and continuous parts of X" are exactly? I'm having some troubles to understand your notations and context...where the integral appears in the relation $$A\psi(x) = f(x)\psi(x)$$, which is the definition of "multiplication operator"?

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid you'll need to learn some measure theory before you can really understand this stuff.

Comment: @GEdgar: for applications to physics, learning about nonseparable Hilbert spaces is not the best use of one's time.

Comment: Could you explain me where to start with? And, in a qualitative way, how the possibility to expand an operator as linear cmb. Of generalized eigenstates is related to the fact that every self adjoimt operator is a multiplication operator, apart from a unitary trasformation?

Comment: Well, you need to learn some measure theory. You can't understand the explanation without knowing what the words mean.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an attractive formalism--and it is attractive--it can't really be made to work in any simple way. There are no generalized eigenstates for a general self-adjoint linear operator on a Hilbert space, because these generalized eigen-states would not lie in the Hilbert space; so it would make no sense to be able to form linear combinations through sums, let alone integral combinations with respect to a parameter. Almost all of the formalism arose out of Sturm-Liouville problems, and there you can do something reasonable. But not for the general self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space. The ideas are so attractive that they caught on, and have been taught ever since Dirac because of the intuitive understanding that someone can gain from such idealizations.

Comment: Ummh..so quantum mechanics fundamentals are based on  mothing? After defining a physics operators, i can't know a priori that such an expansion is guaranteed?

Comment: @Rosario : The classical examples where separation of variables applies will allow Dirac type expansions. Dirac built it for that.